# How to migrate the posts from an old custom legacy blog to a new WordPress website?

Tags: php, posts, database, mysql, migration

I have to migrate the posts of a very old custom legacy blog made in ASP (the posts are stored in a MySql table) into a new WordPress blog.

So I need your help to find the smartest solution to do it, I rule out the idea of ​​doing it manually because the number of posts that should be migrated is really high.

So looking this ER schema: http://codex.wordpress.org/images/9/97/WP3.8-ERD.png
I thought I could create a script that take a post from the post table of my old legacy blog and create a new record on the **wp_posts** wordpress post table of the new blog.

Is it a good solution or exist something better? A WP plugin on something like this?

Tnx

Answer (score 0):

Old unanswered question, but found this via the googles (1st answer) that appears to have good info / links (might be useful to someone):

[What is the required format for importing posts into Wordpress?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/82399/what-is-the-required-format-for-importing-posts-into-wordpress)

Plus this one from the Codex, which has info on importing from all sorts of formats, including RSS and XML. https://codex.wordpress.org/Importing_Content

If your old blog can export to one of those formats (or you can write a custom exporter into those formats), those links could give you a start.